# Render Farms: Blender 'Network Render' Vs Multiple Computers + 'Place Holder' / Network Path

Tags: rendering, network

Just a quick question -- 
I'm wanting to setup a small 'render farm' for an animation I'm working on.

There's [a tutorial here on building and configuring one](https://cgcookie.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-renderfarm), which uses the network render plugin.

Alternatively, there's [another I saw here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3EcpkwLCFI) that looks at using a network save location, and setting up individual computers with the scene + assets all rendering different frames of the animation, and it uses a method to check if a frame has already been rendered.

The 'network render' makes the most sense (apart from some additional setup) - however, feels more straight-forward as compared to the second method.

I was just wondering: is there any difference between the two, or are they essentially achieving the same thing? (I know, logically, it would seem it's the same thing, but I am curious if there's anything else taking place "under the hood" that could be of more benefit one way or another).

Thanks!

Comment: You should also checkout https://www.flamenco.io/ , which is used in blender cloud.